# How to target .NET Standard 2.0?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code, .net-standard

I'm trying to create a new .NET MVC application targeting .NET Standard 2.0.
When I do a `dotnet new mvc -au None` I end up with an app targeting `aspnetcore2.0`. Since I want the project to target `netstandard2.0` I had to manually craft the `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Everything builds nicely, but when I do a `dotnet run` things go south:

> A runnable project should target a runnable TFM (for instance,
>   netcoreapp2.0) and have OutputType 'Exe'.

Relevant info:

```
dotnet --version
2.1.4
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should target `netcoreapp2.0`.

### Explanation

.Net Standard is an implementation of the .Net Base Class Library which defines a standard list of APIs that you can program against. As a result, your project can target .Net Standard just as it can target .Net X.X.

When you chose DotNetCore 2.0, you were really choosing an ***implementation*** of the .net standard that consumes classes based on .net standard 2.0. Those classes are typically compiled into a class library (dll) which is not executable. Alternatively, you could build an implementation of classes within an application project based on the standard. DotNetCore applications are console applications that are ***executable***.

See the section: [Relationship to .NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/index#relationship-to-net-standard)

Comment: If I'm reading you correctly, not all types of projects are able to target `netstandard2.0` ? E.g. ASP.NET Core projects have to target `aspnetcore2.0`, while Class Library projects can target `netstandard2.0`?

Comment: Correct. .NET Standard projects can only be used for non-executable portable assemblies. Since AspNetCore assemblies are executable, they do not meet that requirement, and you have to target `netcoreapp2.0`.

Comment: @NightOwl888: Thanks for your feedback. On a side note: Is it me or is this fact not properly emphasized in all the various documents? I mean, I saw Immo's video, heard him talk on a podcast, read the articles, saw that large compatibility matrix, but it never occurred to me/caught my eye that .NET Standard itself is meant only for non-executable assemblies.

Comment: @Robotron - Maybe you are right, I haven't payed much attention. Some of us have been using .NET Standard for over a year now, and others are now just dipping their toe in the water. This behavior makes sense if you look at the [.NET Standard chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) - .NET Standard shares libraries between platforms, but an executable can only target a single platform. However, I have to admit I have been caught out a few times targeting .NET Standard in NUnit projects and spinning my wheels trying to work out what the problem was.